# Variables not passing between IF statements PHP

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, statements

Okay so I'm writing a piece of code which checks a number of conditions which are set in IF statements in order to display a button to signup for a website. However, the variables I am declaring as true/false in my IF statements don't seem to be transferring over to the statement where it determined whether they are all true. Ive looked online and can't seem to find any problem like this anywhere, so i don't know if its me being stupid or there is a genuine problem. Here's my code:

```
<?php

include_once('db_conx.php');

//CHECKING USERNAME IS NOT TAKEN 

if(!empty($_POST["username"])) {

    $usernameAuth = false; 
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
    $queryUname = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
    $username_check = mysqli_num_rows($queryUname);

    if($username_check>0){
        echo "Username Not Available.";
    } else {
        echo "Username Available.";
        $usernameAuth = true;
    }
}

//CHECKING EMAIL HAS NOT BEEN USED BEFORE

if(!empty($_POST["email"])) {

    $emailAuth = false;
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
    $queryEmail = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
    $email_check = mysqli_num_rows($queryEmail);

    if($email_check>0){
        echo "Email already registered.";
    } else {
        $emailAuth = true;
    }
}

//CHECKING THAT THE PASSWORDS MATCH AND ARE VALID

if(!empty($_POST["password1"]) && !empty($_POST["password2"])) {

    $passAuth = false;
    $password1 = $_POST['password1'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];

    if($password1 != $password2) {
        echo "Your passwords do not match.";
    } elseif(!preg_match("#[0-9]+#",$password1)) {
        echo "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Number!";
    } elseif(!preg_match("#[A-Z]+#",$password1)) {
        echo "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Capital Letter!";
    } elseif(!preg_match("#[a-z]+#",$password1)) {
        echo "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Lowercase Letter!";
    } else {
        $passAuth = true;
    }
}

//CHECKING TO SEE IF ALL THE VALIDATION CONDITIONS ARE MET

if(!empty($_POST["checkinput"])){

    if(($usernameAuth) && ($emailAuth) && ($passAuth)){
        echo '<button id="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" onclick="signup()" name="action">Register<i class="material-icons right">send</i></button>';
    } else {
        echo 'shite';
    }
}
?>
```

If you need to know more or want any more pieces of the project, just say and I'm happy to provide them.

UPDATE

Added the AJAX JQUERY and index.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
  <!--stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

  <!-- MaterializeCSS -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

  <!-- fullPage.js -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fullPage.js-master/jquery.fullPage.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/jquery.easings.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fullPage.js-master/vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fullPage.js-master/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>

    <!--TILE SCROLLING-->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            verticalCentered: true,
            sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#2c3e50', '#34495e'],
            anchors: ['homepage', 'Login', 'Register'],
            afterRender: function(){
                //playing the video
                $('video').get(0).play();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <!-- VALIDATING THE NEEDED FIELDS -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //CHECKING USERNAME

        function UserAvailability() {
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: "scripts/validation.php",
            data:'username='+$("#username").val(),
            type: "POST",
            success:function(data){
                $("#user-availability-status").html(data);
                },
            error:function (){}
            });
        }

    //CHECKING EMAIL

        function EmailAvailability() {
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: "scripts/validation.php",
            data:'email='+$("#email").val(),
            type: "POST",
            success:function(data){
                $("#email-availability-status").html(data);
                },
            });
        }

    //CHECKING PASSWORDS MATCH

        function passwordCheck() {
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: "scripts/validation.php",
            data:'password1='+$("#password1").val()+'&password2='+$("#password2").val(),
            type: "POST",
            success:function(data){
                $("#password-status").html(data);
                },
            });
        }

    //SIGNUP

        function checkInput() {
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: "scripts/validation.php",
            data:'checkinput=success',
            type: "POST",
            success:function(data){
                $("#register-button").html(data);
                },
            });
        }

    //CHECKING LOGIN DATA IS VALID

        function register() {
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: "scripts/validation.php",
            data:'forename='+$("#firstName").val()+'&surname='+$("#lastName").val(),
            type: "POST",

            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section " id="section0">
      <video autoplay loop muted id="myVideo">
        <source src="video/homeVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
        <div class="layer">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li data-menuanchor="Login"><a href="#Login">Login</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="Register"><a href="#Register">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="layer">
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section1">
        <div class="loginCard">
            <form action ="scripts/login.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" id="usernameLogin" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="password" id="passwordLogin "name="password" placeholder="Password" onblur="loginCheck()">
                <span id="login-status"></span>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="registerCard">
            <form action="scripts/signup.php" method="post" class="input-field" oninput="checkInput()">
                <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" id="first_name" class="validate" >
                <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Surname">
                <input type="text" nenter code hereame="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" onkeyup="UserAvailability()">
                <span id="user-availability-status"></span>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" onkeyup="EmailAvailability()">
                <span id="email-availability-status"></span>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password1" placeholder="Password">
                <input type="password" name="passwordVerify" id="password2" placeholder="Re-enter Password" onkeyup="passwordCheck()">
                <span id="password-status"></span><br>
                <span id="register-button"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. Is your form sending a `POST`? I think your logic also could be simplified a bit.

Comment: yeah I'm not worrying about injections just now, my priority is just getting this sorted. And its because its part of a JQUERY AJAX form which is checking the username and email against the database and the passwords against each other, and i couldn't think of a way to do it all in one query

Comment: Is this correct? if($username_check>0){
        echo "Username Not Available.";
    }

Comment: Can you post the AJAX part? Where does this currently fail?

Comment: Updated with the AJAX part.

Comment: Does the AJAX fire correctly? Where in the PHP does it fail or does it not make it to the PHP?

Comment: Yep, all the AJAX and PHP works perfectly, verifying the email, username and passwords. The only problem is that the usernameAuth, passAuth and emailAuth are not being passed from the IF statements and I'm getting an error when it tries to display the button for undeclared variables usernameAuth, emailAuth and passAuth.

Comment: You get undefined variable notices and then `shite`? Your three cases, `($usernameAuth) && ($emailAuth) && ($passAuth)` will never be met at once because you send each field separately.

Comment: I thought though that once the variable has been declared as 'true' it would remain in that state until changed? so surely if they're all changed to true even if its not in one function it should still recognise that they are all true?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it, when these POST params are empty, the variable was never initialized.

A variable that will be used further down and not just inside this if-statement, should have its initial default value initialized outside all the if-statements.

Change

```
if(!empty($_POST["username"])) {

    $usernameAuth = false;
```

to

```
$usernameAuth = false; 
if(!empty($_POST["username"])) {
```

AND

```
if(!empty($_POST["email"])) {

    $emailAuth = false;
```

to

```
$emailAuth = false;
if(!empty($_POST["email"])) {
```

AND

```
if(!empty($_POST["password1"]) && !empty($_POST["password2"])) {

    $passAuth = false;
```

to

```
$passAuth = false;
if(!empty($_POST["password1"]) && !empty($_POST["password2"])) {
```

Or even better yet, initialize the initial default value of all these flags at the top of the file:

```
$usernameAuth = false; 
$emailAuth = false;
$passAuth = false;
...
if(!empty($_POST["username"])) {
...
if(!empty($_POST["email"])) {
...
if(!empty($_POST["password1"]) && !empty($_POST["password2"])) {
```

That will make the logic much cleaner to follow, and leave less room for a mistake.

And then check for more of these oversights.

Comment: I've tried your last solution, and what happens is that they all remain false and the button does not show still. There seems to be a problem where when the variables state is being changed to 'true' it is not being passed to the final IF statement where it is checking that they are all true.

Comment: @RossMuego Put some echos in the else branches that set the values to true...you're probably never entering them.

Comment: So after setting them to true try echoing them to see if its changing?